# jQuery .on('click', function() only works on 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick, woocommerce

I have a custom jQuery script in which the .click(); functions works fine, but the .hide(); and .show(); only triggers for the second click.

HTML:

```
<div id="ivpa-content" class="ivpa-register ivpa_registered" data-variations="TLDR">    
    <div class="ivpa_attribute ivpa_text ivpa_background ivpa_selection" data-attribute="pa_foetel">
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="elso-foetel"></span>
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="masodik-foetel"></span>
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="foetel-nelkul"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="ivpa_attribute ivpa_text ivpa_background ivpa_selection" data-attribute="pa_foetel-adag">
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="foetel-fel-adag"></span>
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="foetel-teljes-adag"></span>
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="a-foetel-nelkul"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="ivpa_attribute ivpa_text ivpa_background ivpa_selection" data-attribute="pa_leves">
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="elso-leves"></span>
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="masodik-leves"></span>
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="leves-nelkul"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="ivpa_attribute ivpa_text ivpa_background ivpa_selection" data-attribute="pa_leves-adag">
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="leves-fel-adag"></span>
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="leves-teljes-adag"></span>
        <span class="ivpa_term ivpa_active ivpa_instock" data-term="a-leves-nelkul"></span>
    </div>
    <a class="ivpa_reset_variations" href="#reset">Clear selection</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
var foetel_nelkul = $('[data-term="foetel-nelkul"]');
var foetel_adag = $('[data-attribute="pa_foetel-adag"]');
var elso_foetel = $('[data-term="elso-foetel"]');
var a_foetel_nelkul = $('[data-term="a-foetel-nelkul"]');
var foetel_fel_adag = $('[data-term="foetel-fel-adag"]');
var foetel_teljes_adag = $('[data-term="foetel-teljes-adag"]');

$(a_foetel_nelkul).hide();
$(foetel_adag).hide();

$(elso_foetel).on('click', function () {
    $(foetel_adag).show();
    if ($(foetel_nelkul).hasClass('ivpa_clicked')) {
        foetel_nelkul.click();
    }
    if ($(a_foetel_nelkul).hasClass('ivpa_clicked')) {
        a_foetel_nelkul.click();
    }
});
$(foetel_nelkul).on('click', function () {
    $(foetel_adag).hide();
    if ($(elso_foetel).hasClass('ivpa_clicked')) {
        elso_foetel.click();
        if ($(foetel_fel_adag).hasClass('ivpa_clicked')) {
            foetel_fel_adag.click();
        }
        if ($(foetel_teljes_adag).hasClass('ivpa_clicked')) {
            foetel_teljes_adag.click();
        }
        if ($(a_foetel_nelkul).hasClass('ivpa_clicked')) {
            a_foetel_nelkul.click();
        }
    }
```

So when I click on the element $(elso_foetel) it shows up, but i need to click twice on the $(foetel_nelkul) to make the $(foetel_adag) hidden; and vice versa.

Thanks in advance for all the help! I really need to get through this.

Comment: Did you try reversing the `if` condition. Also, you seem to have some logical flaw, when you click one element, it triggers a click on the other element, which again triggers a click on the first element etc.

Comment: Well, there's a plugin which generates clickable field for each attributes of a Woocommerce Variable Product.
Clicking on it registers the chosen attribute to the container div's data-attribute=" ". It's too much for me, had to chose the easy way

Comment: @ÁkosFerenczi - Did you check your console for any errors?

Comment: No errors, but what adeneo said about the mess with the clicks has some truth in it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YGECrkZP
Here is the script what does the job. I think the magic begins at the 284th line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the function from `.on()` to:

```
$(foetel_nelkul).click(function() {
    // All of your code in the other function here
});
```